# Aspect Oriented Programming profiling execution time

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am trying to profile execution time of a simple method, using Aop. when i try to execute the code i keep getting the error repeatedly.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class SpringAOPDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "applicationContext.xml");
    Business bc = (Business) context.getBean("myBusinessClass");
    bc.doSomeOperation();
}

}
```

This is my XML class, ApplicationContext.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Enable the @AspectJ support -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean id="businessProfiler" class="com.veerasundar.spring.aop.BusinessProfiler" />
<bean id="myBusinessClass" class="com.veerasundar.spring.aop.BusinessImpl" />
</beans>
```

I keep on getting this error,

```
    Apr 22, 2014 9:00:11 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1090c56: startup date [Tue Apr 22 21:00:11 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 22, 2014 9:00:11 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Apr 22, 2014 9:00:11 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b191c4: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,businessProfiler,myBusinessClass]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:965)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.veerasundar.spring.aop.SpringAOPDemo.main(SpringAOPDemo.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.<init>(DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.java:49)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.GlobalAdvisorAdapterRegistry.<clinit>(GlobalAdvisorAdapterRegistry.java:31)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:47)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: You're missing a dependency or mixing versions etc. Please consider using Maven or other dependency management tool.

Comment: do you have spring-aop jar in your classpath ?

Comment: BTW, Spring AOP has out of the box `PerformanceMonitorInterceptor`

Comment: @Amit yes i have added spring_aop jar in my classpath and still i end up getting this error :(

Comment: @ArtemBilan i am newbie to spring aop, can u suggest  any tutorials to understand PerformanceMonitorInterceptor , i need to log the execution time of modules

Comment: @DaveNewton I tried using Maven, i get the following error Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was 
 cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
 Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing aopalliance-1.0.jar from your classpath.